# Failed to connect to mongodb with docker-compose

Tags: java, mongodb, docker

I have a web server written in java that connect to mongo db

my docker-compose file is:

```
version: "3.2"

services:

  web:
    image: org/web-server:latest
    restart: always
    env_file: .env
    depends_on: 
      - mongo
    ports:     
     - "8080:9999"
    networks:
      - web-network
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    networks: 
      - web-network
    volumes: 
      - "mongodbdata:/data/db"

networks:
    web-network:
volumes: 
    mongodbdata:
```

Exception is:

```
org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017
bot_1    | com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
bot_1    |  at com.mongodb.internal.connection.AsynchronousSocketChannelStream$OpenCompletionHandler.failed(AsynchronousSocketChannelStream.java:124)
bot_1    |  at sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:128)
bot_1    |  at sun.nio.ch.Invoker$2.run(Invoker.java:218)
bot_1    |  at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl.java:112)
bot_1    |  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
bot_1    |  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
bot_1    |  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
bot_1    | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
bot_1    |  at sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
bot_1    |  at sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:252)
bot_1    |  at sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.finish(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:198)
bot_1    |  at sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.onEvent(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:213)
bot_1    |  at sun.nio.ch.EPollPort$EventHandlerTask.run(EPollPort.java:293)
bot_1    |  ... 1 common frames omitted
```

Comment: you are running compose file or docker run command ?

Comment: also from your application, what is your mongo uri ?

Comment: uri is mongodb://localhost: 27017
run docker-compose

Comment: can you try using uri `mongodb://mongo: 27017`

Comment: @AlexKlimashevsky Are you able to connect to the mongo using mongo client?

Comment: You should also pass the version name along with the mongo db say `image:mongo:4.2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to connect to mongo with `mongodb://localhost:27017` your application look for local container which is the one that host only the app name `web` in docker compose

The easiest way to solve this problem is to set your uri to `mongodb://mongo:27017`
But if you like you use `mongodb://localhost:27017` you should use `Link` option in docker compose.

For more info look at this doc: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#links